# PHP text with ? and : in it

Tags: php

I came over a line in a script that I'm trying to fix. But I can't understand what it means. And it's not easy to search on google either, as it's used in search with google as well.

```
$row["name"] = $row['user_nick'] ? $row['user_nick'] : $row['user_firstname'];
$row["name"] = $row['user_nick'] ? str_replace(array("*","$"),array('<img src="#" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>','<img src="#" width="22" border="0" height="22">'),$row["name"]) : $row["name"];
```

(just removed the image files)

Comment: It's a Ternary Expression

Comment: First line: if has nickname, use the nickname, if not use the first name. Next line: If has nickname, find * and $ in name and replace with images , if hasn't nickname just enter name (I think).

Comment: Thank you both, this answered my question 